# Set Assets.getText to correct path

Tags: meteor

I would like to structure my private folder to contain subfolders of emails. I have lots of emails so I need a better way to manage them. I've tried to structure the folder below however it errors with `Error: Unknown asset`. Is it possible to point the `Assets.getText` to a sub-folder in private. I've tried to set the path a number of ways, however everything produces the same error. 
How do I do it? If it's possible.

```
SSR.compileTemplate( 'htmlEmail', Assets.getText( 'myemail.html' ) );
```

Path: `directory-structure`

```
-app
 -private
  -emails
   -teacher
   -myemail.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an asset relative path:

```
SSR.compileTemplate( 'htmlEmail', Assets.getText( 'emails/teacher/myemail.html' ) );
```

You could also create a shortcut function:

```
Assets.getEmailText = (subFolder, filename) => (
  Assets.getText(`emails/${subFolder}/${filename}`)
);

Assets.getEmailText('teacher', 'myemail.html');
```